# How to connect to Php server from android Device with low android version

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm having a very strange problem. I have an app in playstore with name "Central Department of Physics " Few Days back I was able to connect to my php Databaste from my colors X114 which is Android 4.4 and also checked with Samsung Galaxy with android version samme and it was connected sucessfully but now I haven't changed anything but when I connect to php server I get "Server connection Failed" since few days.

But when I try to connect from Higher android version device, It connects sucessfully...I tried with 3-4 device and result was positive.

So can anyone please help me what should I do to fix this problem??

My activity File is

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mainToolbar;
    private Menu mymenu;

    protected EditText username;
    private Button registerbutton;

    private EditText password;

    protected String enteredUsername;
    private ProgressBar loginProgress;

    private final String serverUrl = "https://forappinthenameofking.000webhostapp.com/index.php";

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainv);
        loginProgress = findViewById(R.id.login_progressv);
       registerbutton = findViewById(R.id.registerbuttonm);

        mainToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainv);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Central Department of Physics");
        mainToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent newPostIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.nepalpolice.cdp.MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(newPostIntent);

            }
        });

        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_field);

        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_field);

        Button loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);


        registerbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, form.class);

                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });


        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                enteredUsername = username.getText().toString();

                String enteredPassword = password.getText().toString();

                if(enteredUsername.equals("") || enteredPassword.equals("")){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    return;

                }

                if(enteredUsername.length() <= 1 || enteredPassword.length() <= 1){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password length must be greater than one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    return;

                }





// request authentication with remote server4

                AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();

                asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl, enteredUsername, enteredPassword);

            }

        });



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        mymenu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UpdateService.class);
                startService(intent);
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.iv_refresh, null);
                Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_refresh);
                rotation.setDuration(500);
                iv.startAnimation(rotation);
                item.setActionView(iv);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

            String jsonResult = "";

            try {

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", params[1]));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", params[2]));

                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return jsonResult;

        }

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            System.out.println("Resulted Value: " + result);

            if(result.equals("") || result == null){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Server connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return;

            }

            int jsonResult = returnParsedJsonObject(result);

            if(jsonResult == 0){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return;

            }

            if(jsonResult == 1){

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                loginProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                intent.putExtra("USERNAME", enteredUsername);

                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "You have been successfully login");

                startActivity(intent);

            }
            loginProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            String rLine = "";

            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            try {

                while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    answer.append(rLine);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

// TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return answer;

        }

    }

    private int returnParsedJsonObject(String result){

        JSONObject resultObject = null;

        int returnedResult = 0;

        try {

            resultObject = new JSONObject(result);

            returnedResult = resultObject.getInt("success");

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return returnedResult;

    }

}
```

Comment: was your server update by any chance (new TLS/SSL, or something like that, could play bad with older libraries in the said devices).

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I have hoste from 000webhost and they haven't send any mail to me for any changes but still I'll ask them...what could be the solution for this..should I host my site in other free web hosting sites?

Comment: errr ... first check if my guess is right.  Then, regarding what to do : best advice, you always end up paying for what you save, ergo : i dont do free. I pay and have full control over my servers.